# How to add Floating Social Media Buttons on Blogger

Tags: blogger, sharing

This serves as a wiki/article on how to add a floating social media buttons on Blogger platform.

The premise: **social media bar that will float to top when content is scrolled down**.

Answer (score 1):

> Before anything else, to prevent copyright issues, etc, I would like
>   to acknowledge Way2Blogging.org as the original source of this amazing
>   share bar, with some tweaks of mine. Original article can be found
>   [here:](http://www.way2blogging.org/2012/06/new-floating-social-sharing-bar-widget-blogger-blogspot.html) .

**Floating Social Media Sharing Buttons**

Here is a simple tutorial on how to put a floating social media sharing buttons on your Blogger in 2 easy steps.

Note: This gadget needs to be put in your Blogger HTML directly. So, you have to open **Edit HTML** in Blogger **Template**, then click **Expand Template Widgets**.

**First, inputting the Javascript/jQuery code.**

Once in the expanded HTML, search for the `</head>` tag and insert these lines of codes directly above/before it:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<style type='text/css'>
/<![CDATA[/
#w2bSocialFloat {clear:both;padding: 6px 0;display:block;background:#E9E9E9;}
#w2bSocialFloat td{padding:4px;margin:0;border:none;}
#w2bSocialFloat td iframe{max-width:82px;width:82px !important;}
#w2bSocialFloat.w2bFloatSocial{position: fixed;top:0;z-index:9999999;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);}
/]]>/
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/<![CDATA[/
// Set the Top Offset
$theOffset = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(b){var a=b("#w2bSocialFloat");a.wrap('<div id="w2bSocialPlaceholder"></div>').closest("#w2bSocialPlaceholder").height(a.outerHeight());a.width(a.outerWidth());e=a.offset().top-$theOffset;b("#w2bSocialFloat iframe[src*=plusone]").closest("div").css("max-width","82px");b(window).scroll(function(){d=b(this).scrollTop();d>=e?a.addClass("w2bFloatSocial"):a.removeClass("w2bFloatSocial");f=b(".post");if(f.length!=0){c=f.outerHeight()+f.offset().top;d>=c?a.stop().animate({top:"-150px"}):a.stop().animate({top:$theOffset+"px"})}else d>=e?a.css("top",$theOffset+"px"):a.css("top","0")})});
/]]>/
</script>
<script src='http://widgets.way2blogging.org/blogger-widgets/w2b-blogger-pinit.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/<![CDATA[/
// Twitter
(function(a,b,c){var d=a.getElementsByTagName(b)[0];if(!a.getElementById(c)){a=a.createElement(b);a.id=c;a.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";d.parentNode.insertBefore(a,d)}})(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
// Google + (plus)
(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)})();
// Stumbleupon
(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="https://platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)})();
// Digg
(function(){var a=document.createElement("SCRIPT"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")[0];a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="http://widgets.digg.com/buttons.js";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)})(); /]]>/
</script>
</b:if>
```

** Change background: #E9E9E9 with the color of your choice to best suit your blog colors.

**Second, inputting the Social Buttons Code:**

Search for `<data:post.body/>` tag and paste these lines of code above/before it:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div id="w2bSocialFloat" class="w2bSocialFloat">
<table  width="100%" class="w2bSocialFloat">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" expr:data-url="data:post.url" expr:data-text="data:post.title">Tweet</a>
</td>
<td>
<iframe expr:src="&quot;//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=80&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&quot;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</td>
<td>
<div expr:id="&quot;w2bPinit-&quot; + data:post.id" style="display: none;visibility: hidden;height: 0;width:0;overflow: hidden;" class="w2bPinitButton">
<data:post.body/>
<script type="text/javascript">
w2bPinItButton({
url:"<data:post.url/>",
thumb: "<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>",
id: "<data:post.id/>",
defaultThumb: "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YZe-IcKvGRA/T8op1FIjwYI/AAAAAAAABg4/j-38UjGnQ-Q/s1600/w2b-no-thumbnail.jpg",
pincount: "horizontal"
});
</script>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" expr:data-href="data:post.url"></div>
</td>
<td>
<su:badge layout="1" expr:location="data:post.url"></su:badge>
</td>
<td>
<a class="DiggThisButton DiggCompact"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</b:if>
```

** If you have found multiple `<data:post.body/>` tags, usually, pasting the Social Buttons Code above the first tag works.

**Tweaks**

1 . If you want to remove the Digg and StumbleUpon buttons, you have to remove these lines of codes from the Javascript/jQuery Code:

```
// Stumbleupon
(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="https://platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)})();
// Digg
(function(){var a=document.createElement("SCRIPT"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("SCRIPT")[0];a.type="text/javascript";a.async=true;a.src="http://widgets.digg.com/buttons.js";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)})();
```

Also, remove these lines from the Social Buttons Code:

```
<td>
<su:badge layout="1" expr:location="data:post.url"></su:badge>
</td>
<td>
<a class="DiggThisButton DiggCompact"></a>
</td>
```

2 . If you want to put a back to top button in the sharing bar, follow these instructions:

2a . Search for the `</body>` tag and paste these lines before/above it:

```
<li class='Back to top' style='list-style: none; width: 0px;' tabindex='0'> <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/><script type='text/javascript'>$(function(){$(window).scroll(function(){if($(this).scrollTop()!=0){$(&quot;#bd-top&quot;).fadeIn()}else{$(&quot;#bd-top&quot;).fadeOut()}});$(&quot;#bd-top&quot;).click(function(){$(&quot;body,html&quot;).animate({scrollTop:0},800);return false})});</script></li>
```

2b . Then, insert the code below in one of the columns [ or `<td>` ] in the Social Buttons Code (it will look something like this):

```
<td>
<a class='backtop' href='#' id='bd-top'>&#8593;</a>
</td>
```

That's it. We're done! Let me know any other tricks to beatify this Blogger gadget. :-)